# How to send email using php with sender name and email address by without server name?

Tags: php, email

How to send email using php with sender name and email address by without server name ?

I want to send email with name : `NUMBERONE` and email address : `admin@NUMBERONE.com`

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:NUMBERONE(admin@NUMBERONE.com)\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I try above code , it's not send email. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Example #4 in the documentation for [PHP mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) answers your question.

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

In your case it should be:

```
$headers .= 'From: NUMBERONE <admin@NUMBERONE.com>' . "\r\n";
```